Differences between the constraints of parameter and port map in VHDL
According to IEEE Std 1076-2002 clause 2.1.1.2:

If an actual signal is associated with a signal parameter of any mode, and if the type of the formal is a scalar type, then it is an error if the bounds and direction of the subtype denoted by the subtype indication of the formal are not identical to the bounds and direction of the subtype denoted by the subtype indication of the actual.

and clause 12.2.4:

If an actual signal is associated with a port of any mode, and if the type of the formal is a scalar type, then it is an error if the bounds and direction of the subtype denoted by the subtype indication of the formal are not identical to the bounds and direction of the subtype denoted by the subtype indication of the actual.

I expected that the association conditions of parameters(of functions) and ports(of components) are exactly the same. However, in simulation practice, I found that they behaved differently.
I tested the rules with following programs. For ports association,
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity foo is
    port (
        sw1: in natural range 1 to 10; -- Tested part
        led1: out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)
    );
end entity foo;
architecture foo of foo is
begin
end architecture foo;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity component_port is
end entity component_port;
architecture behavior of component_port is
    component foo 
        port (
            sw1: in natural range 1 to 10; -- Tested part
            led1: out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)
        );
    end component foo;
    signal sw1_in: natural range 0 to 9; -- Tested part
    signal led1_out: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
begin
    p1: foo
    port map (sw1 => sw1_in, led1 => led1_out);
end architecture behavior;

And for parameters association,
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity function_constraints is
end entity function_constraints;

architecture behavior of function_constraints is
    signal my_lv : natural range 1 to 10; -- Tested part
    signal my_return : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
begin
    process
        function my_func(signal lv: natural range 0 to 9) -- Tested part
            return std_logic_vector is 
        begin
            return "0000";
        end function;
    begin
        my_return <= my_func(my_lv);
        wait for 5 ns;
    end process;
end architecture behavior;

I put different sets of formals and actuals in the parts denoted by comment "-- Tested part" of the two entities mentioned above respectively. These sets of formals and actuals are all of natural type with different constraints. Then I compiled them with Questa Intel Starter FPGA Edition-64 2021.2, and ran the simulation. Here is the records of my experiment:
port map



formal
actual
compilation
run




null
0 to 10
OK
OK


0 to 10
null
OK
OK


0 to 10
1 to 10
OK
OK


1 to 10
0 to 9
OK
Fatal: (vsim-3421) Value 0 for sw1 is out of range 1 to 10.



function parameter



formal
actual
compilation
run




null
0 to 10
OK
Fatal: (vsim-3709) Signal formal "lv" bounds 0 to 2147483647 are not identical to actual bounds 0 to 10.


0 to 10
null
Error: … : (vcom-1030) Subprogram "my_func" signal formal "lv" bounds do not match those of actual.



0 to 10
1 to 10
OK
Fatal: (vsim-3709) Signal formal "lv" bounds 0 to 10 are not identical to actual bounds 1 to 10.


1 to 10
0 to 9
Error: … : (vcom-1030) Subprogram "my_func" signal formal "lv" bounds do not match those of actual.




It seems that the association conditions of function parameters are more "strict". But, again, from the rules of the standard, the strictness of association conditions for function parameters and ports should be the same. I expected that all 4 sets of ports in component_port entity reports error as function_constraints does.
Moreover, I noticed that two of the mismatching errors of the function_constraints entity occurred in the runtime phase, shouldn't them be checked in the compilation phase as the other two errors?

Have you tried multiple tools? This could simply be a quirk/bug in this version of questa. Have you also tried with optimisations turned off? (-O0 switch). Also, have you tried using direct instantiation instead of component mapping? Have you also tried using the -pedanticerrors switch to vcom ?

Note subprogram calls are dynamically elaborated while port interface lists are statically elaborated. The latter during linking and loading here executing vcom while the former executing vsim.
